# autoversioning image links INSIDE css and javascript files?

Tags: javascript, css, static, auto-versioning

Inside my PHP application, I'm already successfully autoversioning my static content (CSS, JS, and images), so my URLs look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/include/css/global.1262063295.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<img src="http://example.com/images/logo.1254284339.png" alt="" />
```

The 10-digit **version numbers** are simply the modification Unix timestamp of the individual files.  This is achieved with mod_rewrite and some basic PHP code (see http://particletree.com/notebook/automatically-version-your-css-and-javascript-files/).  So far so good.

---

HOWEVER, here's my problem.

Inside my CSS file, I have links to many background images:

```
background: url("http://example.com/images/dice.gif") no-repeat right top;
```

Similarly in my JS files, I reference different images as well.

Since I want all access to my static content (css, js, images) to have the **version number** included, is there any way to automatically update the links **INSIDE** a .css or .js file so the above css would look like this:

```
background: url("http://example.com/images/dice.1234567893.gif") no-repeat right top;
```

How can this be done automatically?

Thanks,
Konstantin

Answer (score 4):

You can serve your CSS and JS files through PHP as well. For example, rename `global.css` to `global.css.php`. Make sure to send to correct HTTP response headers.

```
<?php // global.css.php
header('Content-Type:text/css; charset:utf-8');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/autoVer.php'); ?>

#cssrule { background: url(<?php autoVer('/img/background.gif') ?>); }
```